# Difference in template arguments C<void ()> and C<void (*)()>

Tags: c++, c++03

I don't understand difference between template arguments

```
template <class T>
class C
{
   T t;
};

void foo()
{
   C<void ()> c1; //isn't compiled
   C<void (*)()> c2;
}
```

What is the type void ()? Such kind of types is used in boost::function..

Comment: `void()` is some callable entity that has no parameters and returns `void`. E.g. a function `void foo()`.

Comment: `void (*)()` is a pointer to said entity.

Answer (score 6):

`void()` is a function type. `void(*)()` is a pointer type. In C++ you cannot have variables of function type, so `T t;` doesn't compile when `T` is `void()`.

Comment: I have never heard about function types.. what can i do with them, if i cannot declare variable?

Comment: @user2319183: You can use them as template parameters, or to derive function pointer types :-) (Check out how `std::function` works.)

Answer (score 1):

By

```
C<void ()> c1;
C<void (*)()> c2;
```

compiler expects you're passing pointer to a function signature. and first one is not a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The first void() is a function, whereas the second void(*)() is a pointer to a function.

Comment: `void()` is a *type*, not a function. Similarly for the second.

Comment: @Kerrek SB The question stated "What is the type void ()", so answering "it is a function" implies that is its type, not that it is actually a function.